# Need to download cool tier files from azure blob storage

Tags: azure-blob-storage

Need to download cool tier files from azure blob storage.

I’m new to azure. I’m trying to download only cool tier files from azure blob storage using python.

Using below code, I can able to get the list of blobs.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connection_string = "<your_connection_string>"
container_name = "<your_container_name>"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

blobs = container_client.list_blobs()

for blob in blobs:

    print(blob.name)
```

I need to download all cool tier files from azure blob storage how could be achieved?

Comment: After listing blobs you can use the `blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
    blob_properties = blob_client.get_blob_properties()` to get the properties in that you can use `blob_properties.blob_tier == "Cool"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Need to download cool tier files from Azure Blob Storage.

You can use the code below to download only **`cool-tier`** files from Azure Blob Storage using the Azure Python SDK.

In my environment, I have two **`cool tier`** files in Azure Blob Storage.

**Portal:**
[image]

Now, using the code below, I download two cool-tier files to the local environment.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connection_string = "xxxx"
container_name = "sample"
local_path=r"<Your local path>"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blobs = container_client.list_blobs()
for blob in blobs:
    blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob.name)
    if blob.blob_tier == "Cool":
        local_file_path=f"{local_path}/{blob.name}"
        with open(local_file_path, "wb") as my_blob:
            download_stream = blob_client.download_blob()
            my_blob.write(download_stream.readall())
```

**Files:**
[image]

Comment: No need to make the extra call to get blob properties. They should be available when you list the blobs.